CKEditor works well with RichTextField but CKEditor Uploader does not work with RichTextUploadingField in Django
I am learning Django Framework and trying to integrate CKEditor into my project.
Here is my models:
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
import datetime
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField

# Create your models here.

class Category (models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
   intro= RichTextUploadingField(blank=True)
   def __str__(self):
    return self.name
  
class Story(models.Model):
  category = models.ForeignKey (Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
  author = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  url = models.URLField(null=True)
  content = RichTextField(blank=True)
  public_day= models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
  image= models.ImageField(upload_to="stories/images", default="stories/images/default.jpg")
  def __str__(self):
    return self.name



The RichTextField is applied and worked well but I do not know why I can not integrate the RichTextUploadingField from CKEditorUploader into my Category at intro field (as captured in picture 2)
here is my setting:
# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static/')


#ckeditor setting
CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/'
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/'
CKEDITOR_IMAGE_BACKEND = 'pillow'

and my urls.py as:
"""MyNews URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include, re_path
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),  # Maps requests starting with 'admin/' to the Django admin site
    path('', include('stories.urls')),  # Includes URL patterns from the 'stories' app
    re_path(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),  # Includes URL patterns from the 'ckeditor_uploader' app
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, 
           document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)  # Serves static files from the 'media' directory



here is my project structure:

